# Reducing Duplicate Cocos2D Code?

Tags: ios, performance, optimization, cocos2d-iphone

Currently I am trying to check the screen boundaries by seeing if a CCSprite crossed the top or bottom of the screen. The thing is, I really want to combine the 2 below if statements into **1** statement. Anyway the only difficult thing I am going to have to do is the following. What I do below is move the CCSprite 1 point inwards to enforce the actual screen boundary. But I just do not see how I can do that with one if statement.

Anyway here is the method:

```
- (void)checkScreenBoundaries {
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    if (sprite.position.y <= 0) {
        sprite.position = ccp(sprite.position.x, 1);
        died = YES;
    } else if (sprite.position.y >= size.height) {
        sprite.position = ccp(sprite.position.x, size.height - 1);
        died = YES;
    }
}
```

Can anyone show me how I can combine these two if's into 1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGFloat yNew = MAX(1, MIN(sprite.position.y, size.height - 1));
if (yNew != sprite.position.y) {
    sprite.position = ccp(sprite.position.x, yNew);
    died = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((sprite.position.y <= 0) || (sprite.position.y >= size.height)) {
    sprite.position = ccp(sprite.position.x, (sprite.position.y <= 0) ? 1 : (size.height - 1));
    died = YES;
}
```

Comment: I up voted your way but I like the other answer's code better since it is easier to read. Thanks anyways! :P

Comment: Yes, it is more understandable and has cached `yNew`, but it has more lines of code :)